# FBAudienceframework in my framework in swift but its giving final class exception

Tags: facebook-ads-api

FBAdLogger is a final class and cannot be subclassed. FBAdLogger
2018-06-19 18:16:46.777370+0530 100MB[28915:293039] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FBFinalClassViolationException', reason: 'FBAdLogger is a final class and cannot be subclassed. FBAdLogger'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112c311e6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111c47031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   100MB                               0x000000010575cbb0 +[FBAdLogger logAtLevel:file:lineNumber:format:] + 0
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111c47b04 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 19
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111c47e9e _class_initialize + 276
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111c4e824 lookUpImpOrForward + 226
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111c5e414 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
    7   100MB                               0x000000010575926c fbadsdk_dfl_load_library_once + 104
    8   100MB                               0x00000001057592ea fbadsdk_dfl_load_AdSupport_once + 21
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001148347ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114835d64 dispatch_once_f + 285
    11  100MB                               0x0000000105755fdb fbadsdk_dfl_handle_get_AdSupport + 48
    12  100MB                               0x0000000105754fd1 fbadsdk_dfl_load_symbol_once + 11
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001148347ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114835d64 dispatch_once_f + 285
    15  100MB                               0x0000000105755fa8 fbadsdk_dfl_ASIdentifierManagerClass + 48
    16  100MB                               0x0000000105760d2d +[FBAdUtility(FBAdDeviceInfoUtility) getAdvertisingIdentifier] + 16
    17  100MB                               0x0000000105760ead +[FBAdUtility(FBAdDeviceInfoUtility) testHashForSelf] + 30
    18  100MB                               0x0000000105693050 __30+[FBAdSettings testDeviceHash]_block_invoke + 24
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001148347ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114835d64 dispatch_once_f + 285
    21  100MB                               0x0000000105693036 +[FBAdSettings testDeviceHash] + 79
    22  100MB                               0x0000000105693584 +[FBAdSettings isTestMode] + 89
    23  100MB                               0x0000000105762958 +[FBAdUtility(FBAdLoggingUtility) displayVerboseDebugMessage:] + 157
    24  100MB                               0x0000000105765f5f -[NSDictionary(FBAdUtility) objectForKeyOrNil:ofClass:] + 271
    25  100MB                               0x000000010576560f -[NSDictionary(FBAdUtility) objectForKey:ofClass:orDefault:] + 70
    26  100MB                               0x0000000105765841 -[NSDictionary(FBAdUtility) numberForKey:orDefault:] + 95
    27  100MB                               0x00000001057658d2 -[NSDictionary(FBAdUtility) integerForKey:orDefault:] + 92
    28  DigiAdz                             0x000000011013df9f -[FBAdPlacementDefinition ingestPlacementData:] + 279
    29  DigiAdz                             0x000000011013de77 -[FBAdPlacementDefinition initWithPlacementData:] + 65
    30  DigiAdz                             0x0000000110151f03 -[FBAdProviderResponseParser parsePlacementDefinitionFromData:] + 398
    31  DigiAdz                             0x0000000110152420 -[FBAdProviderResponseParser parseResponseFromData:successHandler:errorHandler:] + 1222
    32  DigiAdz                             0x0000000110151821 __55-[FBAdProvider parseResponseFromData:canReturnSources:]_block_invoke.216 + 122
    33  Foundation                          0x000000010a743363 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7
    34  Foundation                          0x000000010a7431ca -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
    35  Foundation                          0x000000010a7416b2 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 766
    36  Foundation                          0x000000010a73d776 __NSOQSchedule_f + 364
    37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001148347ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    38  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011483aad9 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 967
    39  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114838f54 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 780
    40  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011484036c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
    41  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114840076 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
    42  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000114d5f169 _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    43  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000114d5ebe9 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException